# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've had this problem before, but then all I needed to do was to clean and rebuild the project. Now that doesn't seem to work anymore. When I start my Asp.Net MVC3 project debugger, the site is opened in my browser. Instead of getting the first page presented in the browser, I get this error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 
Line 31:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 32:         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 33:         <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 34:       </assemblies>
Line 35:     </compilation>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this. Any idea?

Comment: Clean, close the studio, open the project again.

Comment: Is System.Web.WebPages in your references in the project?

Comment: Yes it is! Didn't work to clean and close

Comment: Try deleting the existing reference and reference it again?

Comment: I've tried that and made no difference :/

Comment: Check that the dependencies of `System.Web.WebPages` are also there: e.g. `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` and `System.Web.WebPages.Deployment`. And you can also use the [fuslog viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx) to find out which assembly is missing from where.

Comment: The dependencies are indeed there. I tried running Fuslogvw.exe from the command window but the command was not found...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this problem. Maybe it occurred when I installed .NET MVC v4 over the top of MVC v3, not sure.

Anyway I removed the `System.Web.WebPages` reference from my project. Then in the Add Reference dialogue .NET tab there were two System.Web.WebPages references listed, a version 1.0.0.0 and a 2.0.0.0. I made sure to add the version 1.0.0.0 one as that was the one that was missing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, this led met to the solution. In my case, the whole DLL was missing from our server.. Based on my experience, WebPages 1.0 gets installed along with MVC3 (if you didn't have it any earlier), while there's a separate package for WebPages 2.0 in the MVC4 install. Make sure you install the right version that's referenced in your web.config.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I encountered the problem when I changed the Target Framework from 3.5 to 4.0. VS 2010 tried to be helpful and upgrade ASP.NET MVC from 2.0 to 4.0, which caused a great many head aches. Simply removing the System.Web.Mvc reference and adding the version 2 one back fixed the issue.

Answer (score 25):

The solution for me was to go to my server and install the Web Pages Version 2 on the server.

Go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34600

And download the package and run it.

It was as simple as that.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: This is a standout, since this is on the server.  Mine cropped up after web deploy transfer, i.e. could not be nuget or project related.  Thanks!!!

Comment: As far as I am concerned this is the correct answer. I ran into the exact same thing and installed WebMatrix to make this work for me.

Answer (score 16):

Worked for me:

1. Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
2. Browse
3. Search for "Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages"
4. Make sure all projects in solution have the latest version.

Answer (score 6):

I scratched my head for a while over this problem when I had it. Eventually I noticed that I had the following section in the "runtime" section of my web.config.

```
<runtime>
 . . .
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
. . .
</runtime>
```

As you can see, this refers to version 2 of the assembly, which doesn't match the following code that you also have in the system.web/compilation/assemblies section of web.config.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

The actual assembly referenced in References for the project is indeed v1.0.0.0, so I changed the first chunk of code above to the following, which fixed the problem immediately. I'm not sure how the mistake got there in the first place.

```
<runtime>
 . . .
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
. . .
</runtime>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixet it for me. The reference contained v2.0, the web.config contains the v1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Go to menu: "Tools / Nuget Package Manager / Package Manager Console"

run command `install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, all I had to do was change the property of the external reference: Specific Version from **True** to **False**

After that the project build again.

Answer (score 0):

I have fetch same problem for MVC5.

At First Check your **System.Web.WebPages** assembly from Reference of your project.

1. If not found, then add by select **add reference** from project Reference.
2. If found, any the check version from **Properties** of that reference. Then check your project **web.config** file. May be this two versions are not matching.

For me, I add a reference of version 2.0.0.0. but my web.config file reference it from

`<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />`

and I change it to

`<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />`

it works for me in MVC5.

Please check highlighted section in my attachment for more clearance.

[image: System.Web.WebPages]