# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor, , Version=3.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am using MVC 5, WCF and Unity framework in my application.

I am getting below error when I run WCF service:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +556
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9882460
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.33440
```

I have added System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0 in WCF project, still same error persist.

Do someone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 101):

Be sure that your project targets .net 4.5, that all references are valid and that web AspNet.WebPages.* are in the bin (Release/Debug) folder.

[image: valid refs]

You may also try to reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages nuget packages using this command in the package manager console

```
> Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me. I added the System.Web.WebPages.Razor and it solved my problem.

Comment: Why is this needed in the WCF project at all?  Razor is a web DLL.

Comment: Also, do not confuse `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` for `System.Web.Mvc`. I don't know why MvcContrib thought that was a good name.

Comment: Thanks for last comment. I think that my cry was heard of miles away

Comment: What can I say, I've been looking for an answer to this for 2 nights now.  I just have to install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages nuget package.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2934829 - you really should accept this as the answer

Comment: my project was just Web Api, and had the same problem. I solved the problem by clearing the bin folder :)

Comment: I solved my problem deleting the `System.Web.Mvc` and works!

Comment: This really helped! Thanks!

Comment: @user2934829 Accept the answer, this answer is more than a year old already!

Comment: @zimdanen I think Mahdi K's comment answers yours. In my case I was trying to pass a selectlistitem but I changed it to just use a custom class and map post pull.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. My project was somehow broken after installation of VS 2017 on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the exact error here (among a couple other missing reference errors) on my Win10 x64 system. My issue was (I believe), was caused by uninstalling something from add/remove that ripped out other dlls.

After scouring the internet for a solution, what finally worked for me was the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27785999/692124

> Download and install [Web Pages Version 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34600)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue where WCF was showing error of unrelated MVC assembly (I have multiple MVC projects in solution which are using System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0). I installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages package in the WCF project , ran WCF proj and It worked. After that I had uninstalled all Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages related packages. It worked fine.