# Could not load file or assembly Cascading Failure of EACH DLL

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

```
Could not load file or assembly dotnetopenauth.core

Could not load file or assembly dotnetopenauth.AspNet

Could not load file or assembly NewSoft.Json, 

Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=2.1.0.0
```

One After another after another ...
Builds and runs in Debug ...
Built and Published Yesterday ... no issues with app since Oct 2013, always keeping update package from PM manager MVC 5 EF 6

The stack trace differs for each item ... have been at this for hours ... clean up one issue and the next issue appears. Starting from the Output Window, Error at first appearance: DotNetOpenAuth.Core.

[Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108375/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-3-0-0-0-or)
[References](https://serverfault.com/questions/601671/deploying-mvc-5-1-app-on-web-server)
[Reference(s) Manual](http://forums.asp.net/t/1997385.aspx?Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+System+Web+Mvc+Version+4+0+0+0)
[Binding and Redirect](http://support.appfail.net/discussions/problems/82-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemwebmvc-version2000)
[Assemblies](http://www.christowles.com/2012/08/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html)
[Recompile](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1662)

I have tried, applied, verified and still fix denied:
Have deleted bin and obj ...
Have cleaned and rebuilt and reinstalled packages from PM Manager ...
updated version to match ... Copy Local et: true
Update-Package –reinstall <<some_assembly.reference.name<< ... 
Deploy the project to the server using web deploy type. Checked the changes between server and local ...

**HACK FIX** gined-up a new project, pasted the code over and runs fine ... for one week. Sept 6 go to update, simply added some text to existing paragraph, debugs fine, clean rebuild, publish , BOOM: Could not load file or assembly ... started all over again. The weirdness is this not my only MVC project; it is the only one blowing up.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? What is the FIX?

Comment: How are they referenced? Is copy local is true? Watch the output window for first error and start from that file

Comment: These are messages you see in Visual Studio? And you say it works when doing Debug builds but not when doing Release builds?

Comment: Try doing a Google search for ".net fusion log viewer" and see if maybe that program can tell you what is going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the .NET Fusion log viewer: seems back to basics may well be the best idea for looking under the hood. 

Also, a Nod and Thank You to [Drew McGowen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2478565/drew-mcgowen "excellent member contributor") for taking the time clean up my poor posting and teach a little about the basics on communiting well in these boards. :)