# Not able to store data in cookie in success callback of ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, asp.net-web-api, ajaxform

I am calling ajax method to Web API and it is returning json object. It contains multiple key value pairs.

I am using jquery.cookie.js from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie. In success callback I am trying to store response data into cookie, but I am getting "**Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function**" error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:12345/Login",
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: (data),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    success: handleData,
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});



function handleData(data) {
    $.cookie("example", "foo");
    $.cookie("userid", JSON.stringify(data["userid"]));
}
```

When I call below code in javascript tag it works. same does not work when I use same code in ajax Success callback.

```
$.cookie('menu-data', "Hello");
alert($.cookie("menu-data"));
```

i can store these data in Local storage.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I was referencing  jquery.js file in master page and as well as in content page. After removing one of this, problem got solved.

Comment: mark an answer on this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108375/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-3-0-0-0-or