# CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I built a simple Web API project that reads data from a database. I am using VS 2012 and it works fine on my win7 machine. I have published the web application to a local folder and deployed this to a different win7 machine. However, on trying to access the URL on the 2nd machine, it gives the error above.

This is the erroneous line:

**

```
 Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 30:       <namespaces>
Line 31:         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
Line 32:         <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
Line 33:       </namespaces>
Line 34:     </pages>

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\rcItems\Web.config    Line: 32
```

**

I have checked that Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 is installed on both computers.

I have tried to "Copy Local True" for the System.Web.dll in my project and deployed again.

However I notice that Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack is not installed on the 2nd machine.

Also, this file (and folder) is not on the 2nd machine:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll

Please if someone can shed some light on this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You tagged this as Web API and only mentioned Web API. Are you using [ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246861/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages

Comment: Thanks mason and saj! I was using a template project from the web. I had to add quite a few references (System.Web.Webpages, System.Web.Razor, System.Web.Deployment) and "Copy Local True" before re-deploying it to the 2nd machine. It is returning working now.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure all references are added in the project and Copy Local True before deploying it to second machine, which might not have the components installed.

Thanks Mason and Saj.