# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I have loaded and run my web project on visual studio 2010 but it through the above error..

I have consumed 2 days on searching and trying different solution on it but it is not being solved.I will be very  grateful to you if you will help me.
following my web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
```

Comment: Could you show us your web.config?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i  have added web,config code please view

Answer (score 2):

Recently had this error popping up when I fiddled with the web.config.

Easiest solution was to get the latest MVC update VIA nuget, after first getting rid of the existing error references.

[This](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/) page will show you what to type into your Nuget console in Visual Studio. (You can get other versions from here as well if you are not interested in the latest)

Good luck buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Same question has been asked and resolved here, you can refer to
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246861/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages) hope it helps to you